# Developing with Eclipse and Phonegap/Cordova 3

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-3

It seem the documentation is a bit thin and I assure you I have tried to find this online, but I really don't get how the development process is supposed to work with phonegap and eclipse.

I followed one of the many tutorials and created the Hello World example using the the cordova command line. I then added the android platform and ran the build. After that, I added the andoridy bit as a project in eclipse with respect to existing source as instructed using the subdirectory platforms/android directory. This allowed me to set up the emulator and all worked very well.

The problem I now have is with the development process.

I understand that I have to edit the top level files, not the ones presented in the assets directory of the project in eclipse as these are created using the "build" command. These top level files don't exist in the project I've created in eclipse as they are above the root of the project.

So, my question is ... can I use eclipse to develop this project in a sensible way?

What I'm doing at the moment is editing the android www files and then to pump it up to the cloud build, I'm copying them back up the tree. This seems insane.

Is there a way of having the real files available in eclipse so I can develop them and then build and deploy to an emulator easily?

PS is it my imagination or does cordova build take ages!

**Solution**

I added a folder within the Android project which is a link to the location of the www in the root. This is under advanced options of creating a folder.

Comment: Automate the build: right click on the project -> properties -> Builders and create a new one (i.e. Phonegap Build Android) that executes phonegap local build android from the project directory.  This will make it possible to simply press the debug/run buttons in eclipse and start debugging. Additionally, it may be safer to rename the link to your original www.

Comment: Did you have any problems setting the paths up for that?

Comment: No, I went the easy way: the builder invokes the "buildphonegap.cmd", in that I cd to the project directory and run phonegap local build android.

Comment: The PhoneGap documentation states to just import the platforms\android folder as an existing Android project http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide_open_a_project_in_the_sdk - i've tried it, compiled without error, and was able to deploy to device straight away.

Comment: @aziz I like your proposed solution. Is there a way to make Eclipse run the the `cordova prepare` before doing the `Run as Android App`?

Comment: @aziz To address the issue I commented before, I prepared a `cordova-prepare.bat` (Windows) to execute `cordova prepare` shell command. I then added this to `Proyect Properties->Builders` as a first step. So now everytime I  select `Run As->Android Application` the `cordova-prepare.bat` script is executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this, you must use two different eclipse projects.
One containing the myProject/www folder for developing (let's call it 'top-level project') and one for your specific platform-project (e.g. android, as you already did).

In your top level project, you write your code and, if you feel like, you can even debug up to a certain degree (functions which do not require cordova). Then save and type `cordova prepare` in your CLI. You can then switch to your android project, hit refresh (F5) and run the emulator / device and look for bugs, and make Android-Manifest changes. If you want to change code, switch again to your top-level project and do the same over again.

This seems a bit unhandy, right. Nevertheless, think about cordova not beeing only for developing on android, but also on ios, windows phone, blackberry, ... To access all these platforms, you have to switch to multiple ide's anyway. It makes it a lot easier then, to have the top-level code in a independent project.

Some sidenodes:

1. After doing this process a few times, you will loose not more than 2 or 3 seconds to `cordova prepare` and switch projects. Which is ok, I think.
2. I myself don't just use different eclipse projects, I even use different eclipse installations. This seemed better arranged for me, as it protects me from confusing top and low level files.
3. Even if you develop only for android, you should use two different projects, as 'cordova prepare' (or any cli command containing prepare, as build, emulate and run) would overwrite/delete your files.
4. On my installation, building with CLI takes the same amount of time as it does in eclipse. Which makes sense, as I am using the same sdk for both. However, in the process written above, there is no need to use the cli-build command.
5. If you use just the android platform and don't get easily confused with same-named files in one project, you might link the myApp/www folder in your Android project. In this case, you will only have one project *(Credit for this answer goes to stevemarvell himself, im just adding this here for completeness)*

Comment: Many thanks for the lengthy and considered reply. I have adopted your strategy and find it adequate. At least I now know there isn't a trick I'm missing.

It is most confusing not having the cordova js files in the top level, though this is only an annoyance and does not prevent in browser testing on html5/jquery code.

I have noticed a reduction in build times after the first, which is nice.

Comment: @stevemarvell You're welcome. Nevertheless, I wonder if something didn't work out finally, as you unaccepted my answer, after accepting it at first... :)

Comment: Yes, it's an accepted answer, but I considered my one a fuller solution. However, on reflection, I feel bad and will therefore update :) Bit new to the protocol here.

Comment: Indeed, your solution will work too - I have not seen the note, sorry ;)
I myself would get confused with linking (using same samed files in one project), but if you can handle this, it shure is an easy approach...

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the solution above, i created an 'external tools' configuration that runs the phonegap utility with 'local build android' options and a environment PATH variable set to '/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin' for my Mac. from there, i installed the Eclipse CDT tools and used its 'Launch Group' feature to run the external tool from the top-level project before calling a debug on the platform-specific project.

seems to work fairly well. unfortunately they top-level project doesn't 'remember' the Launch Group execution, so i have to select it from the Debug drop-down each time. i converted the top-level project to a JavaScript as a test, but it didn't seem to help and the 'Run/Debug Settings' in Project Properties are all greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [Multiple Html files in PhoneGap Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756522/multiple-html-files-in-phonegap-android-project/19470400#19470400)

Why I moved to Netbeans with Phonegap 3.0 CLI.  Suited my workflow better.