# Best way to open phonegap project created with CLI in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, command-line-interface

When I create a phonegap folder structure via the CLI (3.0), how do I open this in Eclipse?

When I choose project [New] - [Android project from existing code], the **assets** are taken from the **platforms/android** folder. But I need to change the html and js of the top folder (**www**). These are the files that are being used when I build the project to other platforms (via CLI or build.phonegap). 
Now I change the assets in the editor of the eclipse environment and then manually copy paste the content to the files under www.

Comment: See my answer to an identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680504/developing-with-eclipse-and-phonegap-cordova-3-solved/18692788#18692788

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't. 1) Eclipse is terrible, use SublimeText or literally anything else. 2) Its a right arse, see @miweiss's comment

Answer (score 0):

Actually PhoneGap project structure and Eclipse project structure are somewhat different. But they work in a similar way. If you want to create phonegap project in eclipse then you have to create `html,js,css` within `asset/www` folder. The `java source` files will be within `src` folder(as usual).

If you want to create project without eclipse like with command `phonegap/cordova create MyApp`, then you will get all java source file within `project/platform/android` folder and html,js,css in `www` folder which is auto-created. On the other hand in eclipse you have to create this `www` folder manually.

But project is compiled in a same way whether it is created in eclipse(IDE) or in other text editor.

I have experience in both Eclipse and Text Editor(SublimeText,Vim). I prefer Text Editor because Eclipse sometime creates problem and it needs some extra things like creating www folder and place all scripts,templates,css etc manually.

If anyone whan to go with CLI, then I think SublimeText,Vim,gEdit etc are the best choice for coding.