# Phonegap 3.3 Android Project with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, project

I am trying to update my phonegap 2.1 project to the new 3.3 version.  When I try and make a new project within Eclipse it does not include my source code into the project.  I have tried making a project from the root of my project directory and from the root\platforms\android with the same result.  Each time it makes a project using the CordovaLib directory and not my assets\www directory.  I found another user with the same issue... [Developing with Eclipse and Phonegap/Cordova 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680504/developing-with-eclipse-and-phonegap-cordova-3)  However this solution did not seem to work.  If I make a project with existing code from either two locations my source code(www) directory is not used.  I am using Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.2 Build id: M20130204-1200.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you call `phonegap platform update android` before you import your project in eclipse? When you use the "import existing android project" wizard in eclipse ans browse to projectroot/platforms/android, does it see two projects? (maybe try in a new workspace)

Comment: I am not importing an existing project but rather creating a new one via the option "Android project from existing code".  Once I get the skeletal Phonegap 3.3 project into Eclipse then I plan to move all my www/ files from my existing project into this new one.

Comment: Yes, when I make the new project from projectroot/platforms/android I do see two projects.  In the projects window, the top line shows my project(root/platforms/android) and the second line shows CordovaLIb.  It won't let me select my project and leave CordovaLib unchecked(doesn't recognize it as a project to let me click Finish).

Comment: You have to import the two projects at the same time (there is a reference to the cordovalib project in the app project)

Comment: I have tried that.  If I select both projects and click finish it will create one project under the Eclipse Package Explorer called MyProjectName-CordovaLib.  In that tree are the folders Android 4.4.2, src, gen, assets, bin, libs, and res with files AndroidManifest.xml, build.xml, local.properties, progaurd-project.txt, and project.properties.  In the past, everything would be under the assets folder, however the assets folder is empty in this project.  It is not pulling in the correct data, seemingly.  Best I can tell it is pulling in the data from Projectroot/platforms/android/CordovaLib/

Comment: The assets folder should be in the project named MyProjectName, if the import only imported one project, maybe try in a clean eclipse workspace and/or re-create a new phonegap 3.3 project and retry from the begining?

Comment: Ok, now I am getting somewhere... creating a new workspace allowed me to add both projects(mine and CordovaLib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new workspace solved this problem for me.